# How can I turn an H5 table query result into a Astropy Table?

Tags: python, numpy, pytables, astropy

Usually I query an online database with SQL, but the database is down. I have an H5 file containing the table I need to query. I queried the table using `Table.read_where('condition')`, and have a list of `numpy.void` elements for each row that fit my criteria. Is there any way to take that list of rows and make it into a Astropy table? That's what all of my code previously used, and I'd rather not have to change it. Here is the code I've been using to try and convert it into a Astropy table:

```
import tables
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np

Data = tables.open_file('file_path','r') #opens our .h5 file
DataTable = Data.root.TableName #Points to the table

#Queries the table for rows that meet my 'Condition', and outputs a list of numpy.void's 
#containing integers and floats. Each numpy.void represents a row in my table. 
result = [row for row in DataTable.read_where('Condition')]

#I try to turn the list of rows into a Astropy table to use in the rest of my code.
resultTable = Table(rows=result,names=('Column1','Column2','Column3'))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-aa9501cdbf2a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('FilePath', wdir='FilePath')

  File "Spyder File", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "Spyder File", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "File Path", line 27, in <module>
    resultTable = Table(rows=result,names=('Column1','Column2','Column3'))

  File "FilePath/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/table/table.py", line 420, in __init__
    rec_data = recarray_fromrecords(rows)

  File "FilePath/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astropy/table/np_utils.py", line 196, in recarray_fromrecords
    return np.rec.fromarrays(array_list, formats=formats)

  File "FilePath/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/records.py", line 645, in fromarrays
    _array[_names[i]] = arrayList[i]

ValueError: Can't cast from structure to non-structure, except if the structure only has a single field.
```

I tried passing `result` through `np.rec.fromrecords` to check if that is valid, since the [Astropy documentation] (https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/construct_table.html#construct-table) says it has to be able to pass through that function. It works without any errors.  I'm not sure where to go from here.

My alternative plan is to create a PyTables table of the made up of the rows in `result`, and pull columns as numpy arrays from that. I'd rather stick with just using Astropy since the code I'm using is built around Astropy and it would be easier to stick with that instead of going through and changing it to PyTables.

Comment: First, there isn't such a thing as a scipy table. You import two things that I have little experience with, `astropy.table` and `tables` (is that `Pytables`?)  It looks a bit like one or both uses `numpy` structured arrays (aka `recarray`).  What `scipy` documentation are you referring to?  Also, when asking about an error, **show the whole error, including traceback**.

Comment: The PyTables (tables) function `DataTable.read_where('Condition')` returns a NumPy record array matching the Table's description. That's what you want when creating your astropy.table (if I understand astropy docs. Not sure it can use a record array). You don't need `row for row in` -- just use `result = DataTable.read_where('Condition')`.  astropy.table may require you convert the record array to a ndarray. I'll let you figure that out.

Comment: Structured arrays (and recarray) are documented in https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/basics.rec.html.  The `numpy.lib.recfunctions` submodule now has a `structured_to_unstructured` function that does a good job of converting a structured array into a conventional multidimensional one.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. I mixed up AstroPy and SciPy by mistake. Here is the documentation I meant: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/construct_table.html#construct-table

All I needed to do was switch the iterative `row for row in` with the actual read_where command. Thank you! I'm new to Pytables, and has been copying their basic examples.

Comment: I've added the full traceback as well.

Comment: Tell us about `row` in `result?  If a numpy array, what is the shape and dtype?

Comment: Does this mean your problem is solved? *"All I needed to do was switch the iterative `row for row in` with the actual read_where command."*

Comment: Re: _"I mixed up AstroPy and SciPy"_, should all references to SciPy in the OP be changed to AstroPy?

Comment: I updated the question to reference Astropy instead

Comment: Yes my problem is solved. Thank you all for your help and editing my OP for Astropy. 

I am new to Stack Overflow, is there a way to mark my post as solved or should I just leave it now?

Comment: I will organize my comments into an answer (based on your feedback). Please review and confirm it's correct. That way those that find your question in the future will also find a concise answer (without reading all of the comments). There are still some SciPy references in your OP. I will change them to AstroPy for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation for AstroPy Table](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/construct_table.html#construct-table), the first argument can be a NumPy structured array or 1-d homogeneous array (same type).

The PyTables (tables) function `DataTable.read_where('Condition')` returns a NumPy record array matching that Table's description (aka dtype in NumPy terminology). So, you want to use the returned array to create your AstroPy Table. You don't need `row for row in` in the Pytables call; just use `result = DataTable.read_where('Condition')`.

Note: By default, `astropy.table` will use the field names from the NumPy array. You can view them with (`print (result.dtype)`. Adding the `names=` parameter overrides the default names with the names you provide.

Updated code showing that change below:

```
Data = tables.open_file('file_path','r') #opens our .h5 file
DataTable = Data.root.TableName #Points to the PyTable table

#Queries the table for rows that meet my 'Condition', and 
# returns a NumPy record array with dtype matching the table description
result = DataTable.read_where('Condition')

#reference the Numpy Array to create a AstroPy table for use in the rest of my code.
resultTable = Table(rows=result,names=('Column1','Column2','Column3'))
```